# Tabbed control for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I'm using Delphi XE8.

I want to create a tabbed control, with each tab having its own panel. I tried TTabControl, for which I can create different tabs. But when I drop a component on the control with the first tab active, it remains visible when I change the tab (TabIndex). How can I in design time create different layouts for the different tabs? Or am I using the wrong component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the wrong component. You need to use [`TPageControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TPageControl). Each page of a page control has its own distinct set of controls. From the documentation:

> TPageControl is a set of pages used to make a multiple page dialog
>   box.
>
> Use TPageControl to create a multiple page dialog or tabbed notebook.
>   TPageControl displays multiple overlapping pages that are TTabSheet
>   objects. The user selects a page by clicking the page's tab that
>   appears at the top of the control. To add a new page to a TPageControl
>   object at design time, right-click the TPageControl object and choose
>   New Page.
>
> To create a tabbed control that uses only a single body portion
>   (page), use TTabControl instead.

Comment: The answer to that question can be found in the documentation quote in the answer. Please read it more carefully.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Thanks again.

Comment: To be fair, the documentation for a **TPageControl** is far more clear as to the difference between it and a **TTabControl**.  But if your *starting* point is the **TTabControl** documentation this is much less helpful in directing you to the **TPageControl** or explaining the difference (not completely unhelpful, but far less so - the only direct reference to **TPageControl** is w.r.t wishing to disabling individual sheets).